# replace a value in a file with a group variable using Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline which uses azure devops group variables, however one of the tasks in the pipeline needs to access a value which is stored in a config file in the repo. Currently this value is hard coded. I wanted to use the group variable to substitute the variable in this config file.

eg the config file has this value as below for tunnel_name i want to use the azure group variable $(tunnelname) instead, the file below is outside the yaml file but in the same repo directory

```
capabilities: [
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        platformName: 'Windows 10',
        browserVersion: 'latest-1',
        'sauce:options': {
            screenResolution: '1920x1080',
            tunnelIdentifier: "tunnel_name",
            build,
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task to replace the value.

For example, I set a test variable group:
[image]

In the repo, I have a config with the text:
[image]

Then use a [Replace In Files Text By Text task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Samayas.azuredevops-samayas-replaceinfiles&targetId=4098aa52-96d5-4130-be7f-11295fcf3256&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) to replace the value and a publish task to download the file and check the result .

[image]

Here is the yaml:

```
variables:
- group: test variable group

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: ReplaceInFilesTextByText@2
  inputs:
    parameterSearchDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    parameterSearchText: 'tunnel_name'
    parameterReplaceText: '$(tunnelname)'
    parameterTypeOfSearch: 'filesSearchPattern'
    parameterFilesPattern: '*.config'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    artifact: 'checkfile'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```